# Central logging solution for enterprise application & on-prem only

Tags: logging

I'm looking after a number of applications that I inherited when I joined my company. These app had no tiers and no logging mechanism. New apps that I developed are using log4net. I have two web servers behind F5 load balancer and there are at least 6 such pairs on which my applications are distributed. It is a nightmare to go out and look at log files. Not to mention each application has tiers and each tier writes it own log. I now need a central log management. I'm developing primarily on .Net and I have started to develop core level modules using Serilog.

End result would be replacing log4net with Serilog but the main issue still remain. I can arrange a SQL Server database dedicated to collect all the logs from all the applications but reading about it on the net, it seems like a bad idea. Other services are out there but they are cloud based and subscription based and I work at a government organization and cloud is a big no-go. Extra funding is also not an option. We are premier partners of Microsoft. If there is an offering for MS, I might be able to make that work but not cloud and App-Insights.

Is there an application available that I can install in-house on a server and get things going?

Comment: Opinion based questions are not suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I understand. Where should I ask, if not stack?

Answer (score 0):

You could check out something like [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) which is a pretty good way to store/search log files. There's also a [Log4Net adapter for ElasticSearch](https://github.com/jptoto/log4net.ElasticSearch).